# Draw lines with jointjs via web

Tags: javascript, raphael, jointjs

Im building a small uml modeler with jointjs and raphael for a small project Im doing... I already draw classes by clicking on a button.

What I want to know specifically is how to get the onclick event working on jointjs classes diagrams, because when I click on the classes they do not work, also they move a little when I click on them, If I could get the onclick working I could probably get the objects clicked and draw the line on the background...

Any other ideas on how to draw the lines... maybe by dragging from one class to the other?

Has anyone done this?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share example using jsfiddle.net

Comment: This is what I want to achieve... http://www.jointjs.com/demos/run.html?unit=uml.classdiagram but as you can see the diagram is being created manually through code, I want to be able to create it through dom manipulation, mouse movement... What I have right now is clicking a button a creating a class or diagrams, what I lack is the ability to create the arrows to relate a class to a diagram or to an interface, and I want to achieve such either by dragging from one class to another or by clicking on them, but dont know how!

Comment: Events seems are not captured inside the "paper" in which the jointjs library draws the diagrams.

Answer (score 2):

this is a sample code for jointjs 0.6, the trick is to use model-id attribute to select the object using jquery:

```
        var rect = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
        position: { x: 100, y: 30 },
        size: { width: 100, height: 30 },
        attrs: { rect: { fill: 'blue' }, text: { text: 'my box', fill: 'white' } }
    });


    graph.addCells([rect]);

    //here is the trick
    $("g[model-id='" +rect.id+ "']").click(function() {
        alert("x");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

jointjs provides the events call functionality. You can call events on your paper div.
Here is an example. May be this can help you out. For more, go for the link.
[List of triggered events on Paper](http://jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.Paper:events)
Code Example:

```
paper.on('cell:pointerdblclick',function(cellView, evt, x, y) {
     demo();
  });

function demo(){
 alert("1");
}
```

I hope this will give help to you.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can bind events to mouseclick of diagram elements , since the mouseclick events are already bound by the joint lib itself.

But, you can definitely bind mousedown/mouseup events to simulate clicks.
You can implement connection creation by clicking on one element (putting the joint object in a temp var) and then clicking on another - invoking the

```
var joint= element.joint(other_element,connection_type)
```

Hope it helps, let me know if you need some more.